How to count # of tokens consumed by OpenAI Assistant while streaming the message
I am using openAI Assistant, I get the streamingUpdate using
streamingUpdate = assistantClient.CreateRunStreaming(thread, assistant);

I could iterate through streamingUpdate and send the response to the client using SignalR api.  however I would like to know how to count the #of tokens consumed in the streaming mode.

I found the way to get the token count
CompletionTokens = assistantClient.GetRuns(threadID).Select(f => f.Usage.CompletionTokens).SingleOrDefault();
PromptTokens = assistantClient.GetRuns(threadID).Select(f => f.Usage.PromptTokens).SingleOrDefault();
TotalTokens = assistantClient.GetRuns(threadID).Select(f => f.Usage.TotalTokens).SingleOrDefault();

